# Watch element on directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have the next code:

```
angular.module("Test", [])
.directive("testDirective", function () {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
      model: "="
    }
    link: function(scope, element) {
      scope.$watch(function () {
        element.find("#input").val().length
      }, function (nv){
        console.log(nv);
      });
    }
  }
})
.controller("TestController", function($scope) {
  $scope.model = "Test";
  $scope.updateModel = function() {
    $scope.model = Math.random();
  };
})
;


<div ng-controller="TestController">
  <div test-directive model="model">
    <input id="input" type="text" /> <br />
    <input type="button" value="Edit Model" ng-click="updateModel()" />
  </div>
</div>
```

The callback of the $watch method in the directive is only executed when the button is clicked. But I want to inspect the changes in that element. Is there any way to make this works?

**Edit 1**

I came to notice if I do

```
scope: false
```

It will not create an isolated scope, so I can access it bidirectionally from the directive or the controller (which is what I wanted). However, it does not allow me to watch the model either...

If I have at the controller:

```
$scope.model.test = 1;
$scope.$watch("model.test", function(v) { log(v); });
```

And from the HTML in the directive:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="model.test" />
```

And then I modify the input field at the view, the `log(v)` is never executed...

Comment: Are you wanting to watch the value of your input box for changes?

Comment: Yes @Darren. Is that possible? Is within a directive, so if I do it with the normal way for a controller it will not work :(

Comment: Ok, I've added an answer with plunker to show you a couple of ways of doing what you might be wanting to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

So, not totally understand what you're trying to achieve, i've put together a simple app that has 2 controllers and a directive.

The directive itself contains a template, which has the HTML for your input and button.

It also has a 2-way bound property on it `myModel` that is used in both the template and is also set from `TestController`.

You can see the 2-way binding by typing in the text box - its input is shown in the text below which is bound on the controller - not directly to the directive.

I have also shown you how you can `$broadcast` an event from your directive and listen in from any other controller/directive etc that may be on your page. Clicking the button will increase the count as shown in the text on the second controller `TestControllerTwo`

Hopefully this will demo what you're after?

You can see the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1swwMSOzksD4qNENnrkJ?p=preview) here

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are doing the watch may not be necessary.  Your code isn't really doing anything practical though so you may need a more complete example.

```
angular.module("Test", [])
.directive("testDirective", function () {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
      model: "="
    }
    link: function(scope, element) {
      document.getElementById('input').onchange=function(){console.log(this.value)}

    }
  }
})
.controller("TestController", function($scope) {
  $scope.model = "Test";
  $scope.updateModel = function() {
    $scope.model = Math.random();
  };
})
;


<div ng-controller="TestController">
  <div test-directive model="model">
    <input id="input" type="text" /> <br />
    <input type="button" value="Edit Model" ng-click="updateModel()" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obviously a testControlelr and a testDirective do nothing practical (that is why the name is test). I want to use watch since it is a lot more complex than this. I can do it via `<input type="text" ng-keyup="function()" />` but that is not the way I want to use either... Thanks for your answer. It works ;)

Comment: `document.getElementById('input')` in a directive makes baby jesus cry :'(

Answer (score 0):

In you controller you don't have to use $watch as it is already two-way data binding. If you want to keep an eye on the element's value of the input text box you can do this in your controller:

In your html:

```
<input ng-change="onModelChange()" ng-model="model" id="input" type="text" />
```

In your JS:

```
angular.module("Test", [])
.controller("TestController", function($scope) {
  $scope.model = "Test";
  $scope.onModelChange = function () {
    console.log($scope.model);
  }
});
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/bDxb5JvM0gWg7vMjgaEm?p=preview